# Spring boot check property before SpringApplication.run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, lifecycle

I want to check for a certain property in application.yml, but i don't know how to get it done. I think it is not possible, because the context has not been started up yet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // want to check the value of my property
    SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to write and execute a method in your main class that opens the application.yml, reads and parses it, and looks for a particular property.  That's just straight ahead Java.   This is just like any other Java class:

```
public class MyAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // want to check the value of my property
        boolean isValid = checkApplicationConfiguration("application.yml");
        if (isValid) {
            SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid application.yml");
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkApplicationConfiguration(String yamlFileName) {
       // put the code to read, parse, and validate here.
    }
}
```

Apparently you can use [Jackson](https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson) to read and parse YAML.